# Possible to have highslide window auto-resize?

Tags: javascript, highslide

I built a form for my website that opens inside a highslide popup, and this form has multiple steps.  However, some steps are longer than others and have more text. Is there a way to have the highslide window automatically resize itself to the exact height of the content when it's done loading?

I've been looking, and I've seen people recommend `hs.reflow` or `hs.resizeTo`, but I have been unable to get either of them to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Huzzah, seems as though I have stumbled on the solution. Simply add `parent.window.hs.getExpander().reflow();` to the highslide popup, and remove any definition of height concerning the popup.